# Як правильно: маршрутка до / на / у Львів?

Tags: вживання-слів, прийменники

Сьогодні стала свідком такої розмови.

Сидять пасажири, і тут заходить пані та питає: "А це маршрутка їде на Львів?"
У відповідь лунає: "Пані, та водій казав, що в українській мові є тільки варіант "до Львова!" На Львів - тільки літаком!" :-)

Далі потенційна пасажирка обурилась, що її виправляють і вийшла. Але мова не про це.

Мене цікавить, чи є варіант "маршрутка на Львів"? Чи це нормативно? І яка відмінність між вживанням усіх цих прийменників?

Comment: Схоже запитання: [«Як правильніше вживати, „в“ чи „до“?»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/271).

Comment: Так, але у цьому питанні йдеться лише про прийменники до / у / в, а мене цікавить ще і "на Львів", адже виходить, що це може бути означення: маршрутка (яка?) на Львів.
Окрім того, була така ситуація, де прозвучало пояснення не від мене, а від оточуючих, тож цікавить, чи справді нормативно вживати конструкцію "маршрутка на Львів"?

Comment: [\[1\]](/questions/2530/) • [\[2\]](/questions/488/). Зʼӓвиласӓ одна думка, спробуӱ її реӓлізувати.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[«Як ми говоримо» Антоненка-Давидовича](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53411/33342.html)***

> ...Узагалі, коли мовиться про рух у напрямі міста, села, селища, тоді
>   треба ставити прийменник ***до***: *«Через кілька днів Ковпак вилетів до
>   Москви»* (П. Вершигора); коли йдеться про дію чи перебування в чомусь, тоді слід користуватися прийменником ***у (в)***: *«У Києві на риночку ой пив чумак горілочку»* (народна пісня). Якщо мета руху в певному напрямі супроводжується ще додатковими поясненнями, тоді після них може стояти замість прийменника ***до — у (в)***: *«Ми їздили на ярмарок у Косів»* (М. Рильський).
>
> ... Прийменник ***на*** вживають також, коли описують процес перетворення:
>   *«звівся ні на що».*

[Мова-ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/orfografiya/u-lviv,-do-lvovu-chu-do-lvova)

> Я їду до Львова по безцінні емоції.

**Великий тлумачний словник (ВТС) сучасної української мов**

> ***[ДО](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53396/861791.html)*** - I прийм. , з род. в. Сполучення з до виражають: Просторові відношення: 1. Уживається на означення місця, предмета або
>   особи, в бік яких спрямована дія.
>
> ***[НА](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53405/909680.html)*** -  прийм. Уживається із знах. і місц. відмінками. Сполучення з прийм. на виражають: Просторові відношення: 1. із знах. і
>   місц. в. Уживається для позначення предмета: а) на якого з метою
>   розміщення спрямовується дія (знах. в. ); б) на якому розташовується,
>   міститься хто-, що-небудь (місц. в. ).

Правильно буде ***"маршрутка до Львова"***.